# Objects In Objective-C Singleton becomes null

Tags: objective-c, properties, null, singleton

First of all I want to say that I am very new at both Objective-C and posting here on stackoverflow.

I am using a singleton in a tab bar application which also reads data from an API located on a web server.

My problem is, that when I first instantiate my singleton it works, but as soon as I change view by clicking in the tab bar something weird is happening. My User object which I have in my singleton is still there, but all its properties are set to null.

My singleton is implemented in the following way:

```
@implementation cacheobject

@synthesize location;
@synthesize currentUser;
@synthesize login;
@synthesize email2;
@synthesize isExistingUser;

+ (id)sharedCacheobject {

    static cacheobject *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}


- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.location = 1;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"DEALLOC!!!!!!!!");


}


@end
```

I am using the singleton in the following way:

```
cacheobject *co = [cacheobject sharedCacheobject];
NSString *first = co.currentUser.firstname;
firstname2.text = first;
```

Whatever view is the first view in my tab bar the singleton works correctly, but as soon as I navigate to another view, my properties are null. Everything is null except for the location property.

I have logged the user object, and in both views the object comes out as:

```
<User: 0x8da1640>
```

And since the hex value is the same my guess is, that it is the same object, but the properties are just null??

Please help, I have spent two days trying to figure this out.

Kind regards.

Comment: Still `dealloc`? not using ARC?

Comment: In the above code you only set `location`, did you really set all other values?

Comment: Yes I am. At least I think I am. I just wanted to log it in case it got dealloc'ed. And the function was there in the example I found on the inter web.

Comment: Yes I set other values other places in the application. You want me to add that code? It gets set via another thread.

Comment: How are you declaring the properties of your user? `strong`, `copy`, `weak`? And are the properties set to `null` or `nil`? Moreover, your singleton implementation is wrong, you should not use `self` to instantiate the object, but `[[cacheobject alloc] init]`

Comment: it should be `sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];` as `self` in a class method is the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

As KerrM suggested the properties in my user class was not declared correctly.

They should be strong and retain but they were weak and nonatomic.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: strong AND retain at the same time?

Comment: @user1385341 what to do for BOOL type ?

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the `sharedCacheobject` each time you call `[cacheobject sharedCacheobject]` but you're only initializing it once. So, the first time you're first setting the object to nil and *then* initializing it in your `dispatch_once` block. Every time after that you're setting the `sharedCacheobject` to `nil` but since the `onceToken` has been used it's never getting reinitialized.

If you call it twice in the same view it should still be returning `nil`, it just so happens that the second time you call `sharedCacheobject` is in another view.

Try changing

`static cacheobject *sharedMyManager = nil;`

to

`static cacheobject *sharedMyManager;`